# Insert Python Dictionary in PostgreSQL using python

Tags: python, json, postgresql, psycopg2

Need help to insert JSON file data into JSON column in postgresql using python

Here is my code:

```
import psycopg2 
import simplejson as json

from psycopg2.extras import Json

with open(r'\*.json') as json_data:
data= json.load(json_data)

def insert_into_table(data):
# preparing json data for insertion
for key, value in data.items():
   print(key)

cols = data.keys()
vals = [data[x] for x in cols]

l = [(c, v) for c, v in data.items()]
columns = ','.join([t[0] for t in l])
values = tuple([t[1] for t in l])

keys = data.keys()
columns = ','.join(keys)
values = ','.join(['%({})s'.format(k) for k in keys])

listkey = list(data)

with psycopg2.connect(database='postgres', user='postgres', password='postgres', host='localhost') as conn:
    with conn.cursor() as cursor:

        cursor.execute("""INSERT INTO public.cluster(clustring) VALUES (%s::json)""", ([listkey[1]]))

        conn.commit()

insert_into_table(data)
```

> Error: 
>   LINE 1: INSERT INTO public.cluster(clustring) VALUES ('clustring...
>                                                             ^
>   DETAIL:  Token "clustring" is invalid.
>   CONTEXT:  JSON data, line 1: clustring

Comment: whats the actual name of the table and the column you are trying to insert your json into?  Can you provide your CREATE TABLE sql-statement in your question?

Comment: @iLuvLogix : edited question with column & table name.